# Exception on NSFetchrequest creation

Tags: swift

I am parsing JSON from a Dictionary into a core data model. When I create a NSFetchRequest to look for an existing entry in the model I get an exception.

AppDelegate class:

```
for dictionary : AnyObject in airports as AnyObject[] {
    let name : NSString? = dictionary.valueForKey("name") as? NSString
    if name {
        var airport = Airport.fromDictionary(dictionary as NSDictionary, context: managedObjectContext)
    }
}

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    if !_managedObjectContext {
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
        }
    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
var _managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
```

Model:

```
class func fromDictionary(dictionary: NSDictionary, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Airport! {
    let id = dictionary["code"] as NSString
    var airport : Airport = airportWithCode(id, context: context)
    return airport
}

class func airportWithCode(code: String, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Airport! {
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Airport.entityName(), inManagedObjectContext: context)
    ^.... Exception point
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "code ==[c] %@", code)
    var error: NSError?
    let results: NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
    var result = results.firstObject as Airport
    if result != nil {
        return result as Airport
    } else {
        var airport = createWithCode(code, context: context) as Airport
        return airport
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: `App.Airport.airportWithCode (App.Airport.Type)(Swift.String, context : ObjectiveC.NSManagedObjectContext) -> Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<App.Airport> (Airport.swift:19)`

Comment: Hi, I don't have time right now to debug it (running to a meeting) but look here: http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2014/06/14/swift-and-the-last-mile I think it's more or less the same problem. Talk to you later :)